# How can we link third party databases (specifically MS Access) to Django for the inspectdb utility?

Tags: django, ms-access, django-pyodbc, inspectdb

I want to just automate model creation and also just double check against my manual models using Django's inspectdb utility. However, the database I want to observe is Microsoft Access and it's not very clear how I can do this properly. There is a django-pyodbc but only works for Django 1.4-1.10. Any thoughts on using Inspectdb for a Microsoft Access database?

Comment: Access/ODBC is not officially supported by Django and the `django-pyodbc` project only supports Python 2.x (which is not supported by Django anymore). You may consider using Django 1.11 which was the last version that supported Python 2.x.